# How to force number to be a string using Google App Scripts batch update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am trying to be able to force Google Apps Script to render a large 16 digit number as a string via the Google Sheets batchUpdate api

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId);
```

So far the only way I have found to do this is to prepend a ' single quote to the number which then transfers it correctly in the string format.

My use case is that I want to set some creditcard numbers, however they are displaying in exponential notation when I set the value.

Comment: Try This: `String(expression);`

Comment: Sorry can you expand where to try this?

Comment: Please share your code. If you're referring to SpreadsheetId, it is defined to be a string parameter.

Comment: I will share code tomorrow. It is not the spreadsheetId it is the data that is passed to the batchUpdate I wish to set the type of data it is

Comment: @user3284707 If the number is not less than 16 digits, for example, when ``{"data":[{"values":[["1234567890123456"]],"range":"Sheet1!A1"}],"valueInputOption":"USER_ENTERED"}`` is used as ``resource`` of ``Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId)``, the value of ``1234567890123456`` is put to a cell "Sheet1!A1" as a string value without a single quote. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.